# How to display rows in jLabel in Java from Ms Access database?

Tags: java, ms-access

I'm currently having a problem with displaying Row Values from MS Access to Java jLabel.

I have a Ms Access database with the name `Table` with 3 rows i just want to display the rows in java `jlabels` see the picture but it shows the first row and I'm currently confused Thanks!

[image: GUI WITH <code>JLABELS</code>]

[image: My MS ACCESS TABLE]

```
try {

        resultset.first();


        String name = "Name: ";
        String dmg = "Damage: ";
        String type = "Ammo Type: ";


        //row1
        weapon1.setText(name+resultset.getString("weapons"));
        weapon1dmg.setText(dmg+resultset.getString("weaponDMG"));
        weapon1type.setText(type+resultset.getString("weaponAmmoType"));

        //row2
        weapon2.setText(name+resultset.getString("weapons"));
        weapon2dmg.setText(dmg+resultset.getString("weaponDMG"));
        weapon2type.setText(type+resultset.getString("weaponAmmoType"));

        //row3
        weapon3.setText(name+resultset.getString("weapons"));
        weapon3dmg.setText(dmg+resultset.getString("weaponDMG"));
        weapon3type.setText(type+resultset.getString("weaponAmmoType"));

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through the result set, otherwise you are reading the first row again and again.

```
try {
     String name = "Name: ";
     String dmg = "Damage: ";
     String type = "Ammo Type: "; 
     int count = 0;

    while(resultset.next){
        count++

       if(count == 1){
            weapon1.setText(name+resultset.getString("weapons"));
            weapon1dmg.setText(dmg+resultset.getString("weaponDMG"));
           weapon1type.setText(type+resultset.getString("weaponAmmoType"));
      }else if(count == 2){
            weapon2.setText(name+resultset.getString("weapons"));
            weapon2dmg.setText(dmg+resultset.getString("weaponDMG"));
            weapon2type.setText(type+resultset.getString("weaponAmmoType"));

      }else if(count == 3)
            weapon3.setText(name+resultset.getString("weapons"));
            weapon3dmg.setText(dmg+resultset.getString("weaponDMG"));
            weapon3type.setText(type+resultset.getString("weaponAmmoType"));
    }
```

There should be a better way of doing it, but I don't have access to the rest of your code to see how to simplify it.